# Has coreaudiod been fixed in Lion yet?

Tags: macos, audio, quicktime, video-editing

I tried Lion a few months ago, but had to revert to 10.6 because of the "coreaudiod bug" – where audio via QuickTime would stop working every few minutes, requiring a `killall coreaudiod` each time. Since I'm a video editor, this would interfere with Final Cut and After Effects, making Lion unusable.

Does anyone know if this issue has been fixed yet in Lion?

Comment: I don't know if that specific issue has been fixed but there are a whole bunch of issues fixed with coreaudio in 10.7.4 -- I only know this because because I'm doing some beta testing of 10.7.4 and some pro-audio interface devices now *specifically* to see if <10.7.4 issues ae finally gone. If you have an Apple Developer ID you can download 10.7.4 and try it out, see if your issue is no longer present.

Comment: Is there a reliable way to reproduce this?  Is it specific to some particular hardware?

Comment: This question is garnering lots of bad answers since the question doesn't refer to a specific bug ( has one even been filed ? ) or a sequence of steps to cause the issue. Please edit this and vote / flag for re opening if it can be objectively answered.

Answer (score 1):

Nope it hasn't. I'm still having problems in Logic because of it. I plug in a headphone cable, unplug it, and suddenly the computer doesn't have sound. Try `killall /usr/sbin/coreaudiod` then relaunch it, I get this:

```
[...] Error: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "?-8?????-8????PDa????@Da????0??????Ԕ?????<????????c".
Aug 14 01:56:48 Benjamins-MacBook-Pro.local coreaudiod[7392] Error: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "?-8?????-8????PDa????@Da????0??????Ԕ?????????????c".
Aug 14 01:56:48 Benjamins-MacBook-Pro.local coreaudiod[7392] Error: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "??c".
Aug 14 01:56:48 Benjamins-MacBook-Pro.local coreaudiod[7392] Error: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "??c".
2012-08-14 01:56:48.994 coreaudiod[7392:707] Exiting due to uncaught exception in main
```

Apparently I've got some low level bug in my operating system or coreaudiod just wasn't compiled right.

Answer (score 1):

Does the headphone connect via USB or line-out jack? If USB, it may be that the USB I/O driver for your headphone is causing the problem. Many I/O drivers for core audio (and all hardware devices) run within the kernel.  A bug in the driver can cause problems with the driver manager code (coreaudiod, in this case) or even potentially the entire kernel.

Is it only with one specific headphone and/or one specific USB type output device?  If its USB (and not line-out), try a different USB connector type (different brand) to see if the same problem arises.  If its line-out, I have no idea what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  Actually I have consistently had problems with coreaudiod spawning ports and generally causing the system to hang since 10.6.0